# Display iframe based on iframe content?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I have an iframe for the blogtalkradio chat that is embedded in a wordpress site.  I'd like to only display the iframe if the chat is available.  I was thinking doing an if statement based on the content of the iframe, anyone know how I can accomplish this?  This is the link to the chat http://www.blogtalkradio.com/flashchat/chat.aspx?HostUserURL=kayakfishingradi

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the content of the iFrame. Your best bet here would be something like a proxy. Create a page on your server that curls the content of the page (which will give you access to it), and use that to run your checks. Then it would just be a matter of an if statement to either echo the chat box or echo something else / nothing.